# CSS Filter Regex JS

Tags: javascript, css, regex, filter

I'm trying to detect if the CSS attribute `filter` of an element already contains some rules.
But my regex never finds any match : `/saturate\(.[^\)]\)/`

Here's a demo for you guys :

```js
var filter = $('div').css('filter');

$('p').eq(0).text(filter.search(/saturate\(.[^\)]\)/)); //Should return something else than -1
$('p').eq(1).text(filter.search(/contrast\(.[^\)]\)/)); //Should return -1
```

```css
div{
  filter: brightness(1.9) saturate(80%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Use `\([^)]+\)` instead of `\(.[^\)]\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\([^)]+\)` instead of `\(.[^\)]\)` in your regexps:

```js
var filter = $('div').css('filter');

$('p').eq(0).text(filter.search(/saturate\([^)]+\)/)); // 16
$('p').eq(1).text(filter.search(/contrast\([^)]+\)/)); // -1
```

```css
div{
  filter: brightness(1.9) saturate(80%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<p></p>
<p></p>
```

The `\(.[^\)]\)` matches `(`, then **any char other than a line break char** (with `.`), and then a single char other than `)` (your negated character class `[^\)]`), and then a literal `)`.

The `\([^)]+\)` will match

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `[^)]+` - 1 or more chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

Comment: Oh, you don't have to escape the `)` inside the `[]` ?

Comment: @Zenoo: No, no need escaping `(` and `)`. Only `^`, ``\``, `]` and `-` require escaping (though in some cases, `^`, and `-` may be used as literals inside character classes, too).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that !

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a `+` in your regex

```js
var filter = $('div').css('filter');
//                                               V here!
$('p').eq(0).text(filter.search(/saturate\(.[^\)]+\)/)); //Should return something else than -1
$('p').eq(1).text(filter.search(/contrast\(.[^\)]+\)/)); //Should return -1
```

```css
div{
  filter: brightness(1.9) saturate(80%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<p></p>
<p></p>
```